# WordPress register_nav_menu suddenly stopped working locally

Tags: wordpress, mamp

Ok, this is a biggie. Here's the deal:

I have upwards of 50 installs of WordPress running on MAMP Pro locally. For some of them I use local/whatever, for others I set up virtual hosts as whatever.local/. WordPress has never had any problems. Yesterday, installed a copy of WP 3.0.1 (fresh, straight off the server), and started templating. Today, I returned to it to continue, first by registing default navigations. I put the necessary lines in functions.php:

```
add_theme_support( 'menus' );

add_action('init', 'register_custom_menu');

    function register_custom_menus() {
        register_nav_menu('primary_menu', __('Header Menu'));
        register_nav_menu('404_menu', __('404 Menu'));
    }
```

Fine, right? I also tried it with register_custom_menu, one at a time. In WordPress, no default menus show up. I've tried:

- Activate a different theme, re-activate the original
- Try Twenty Ten - still no custom navigations although a 'primary menu' is registered in the code, so it is NOT my functions.php
- Tried another theme that I have running locally (that works perfectly in its original place), still no navs
- Delete the entire database and re-install WP
- Delete the entire directory, re-download WP, reinstall
- Delete the virtual host and work from localhost/whatever

So, I have a ton of other WP sites working perfectly fine with nav registering, but I can't create any more? I'm completely, totally lost.

Any input would be appreciated, right now I'm at my wit's end. Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

1. You should be hooking menu registration onto `'after_setup_theme'`, not `'init'`
2. You don't need to call `add_theme_support()` since `register_nav_menu()` takes care of that.
3. You can use `register_nav_menus()` to take care of all your menus at once.

However, the biggest reason this isn't working is because you're not calling your function. The callback on `add_action` should be `'register_custom_menus'` (notice plural). The spelling has to match the function declaration. This is how I'd suggest you rewrite it:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'register_custom_menus');

function register_custom_menus() {
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary_menu' => __('Header Menu'),
        '404_menu' => __('404 Menu') ) );
}
```